# Why is "vi spezzeremo le reni" used?

Tags: grammar

Conoscete quali siano le ragioni per le quali alcuni, cosiddetti, *ultras* nel rivolgersi alle tifoserie delle squadre loro avversarie, dicono o intonano questo ritornello

> Oah! Oah! *Vi spezziamo le reni* ... Oah! Oah! *Vi spezziamo le reni* ... Oah! Oah! *Vi spezziamo le reni* ...

Cioé, perché il riferimento è proprio ai reni, che chiamano "le reni"?

Dopotutto, loro, quegli *ultras*, potrebbero dire "vi spacchiamo la testa" o "vi rompiamo le gambe" o, ancora — volendo rifersi ad un organo interno — "vi rompiamo il cranio / la milza / il fegato *and so on*", ma no, no; loro citano i reni. Perché?

Answer (score 13):

È un riferimento ad un modo di dire di epoca fascista.

Frase originale:

> Affermai cinque anni fa: spezzeremo le reni al Negus. Ora, con la stessa certezza assoluta, ripeto assoluta, vi dico che spezzeremo le reni alla Grecia in due o dodici mesi poco importa, la guerra è appena cominciata!
>   (Benito Mussolini)

[Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spezzeremo_le_reni)

Comment: Thank you! E, direi proprio, io i miei reni ce li ho ancora interi, though.

Comment: In ogni caso, credo che le reni qui di fatto siano una metonimia per la corrispondente parte della schiena; l'idea è di rompere la schiena a qualcuno in modo che cada senza potersi più rialzare, è un'espressione in cui c'è accanimento e umiliazione sul nemico.

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/reni/

Answer (score 7):

*Rene* is the part of the body, plural *i reni*. But *le reni* (only plural) means the lower part of the back and is mostly used in figurative sense. So *spezzare le reni* is “to break the back” (probably not used in English), that is, “to defeat”.

It's similar to *le calcagna* that's only used in figurative sense; the heels in proper sense is *i calcagni*. In particular

> avere qualcuno alle calcagna, avere qualcuno alle reni

have the same meaning.

As miniBill says, *spezzeremo le reni* was used by Mussolini. Most people at the soccer field don't really know where the phrase comes from and they say it just because they heard it somewhere. Unfortunately, other people do know and use it on purpose. In any case, it's pathetic.